# Pig on mapreduce mode is stuck on dumping hdfs data in Hortonworks HDP

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I have some data files in my Hortonworks HDFS location. My requirement is to dump HDFS data in pig shell using pig-mapreduce mode. After loading the file data from HDFS, when trying to dump the data in pig shell using DUMP command, the map reduce job is getting stuck at 0% and not completing the job as well for a long time.
Followed the given below steps:

1) Start pig on mapreduce mode:

```
pig -x mapreduce
```

2) Load data into pig from a HDFS directory:

```
mapdata = load 'hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-east-2.compute.internal:8020/user/abc/datadir1' as (a:map[chararray]);
```

3) Print data:

```
dump mapdata;
```

After executing the 3rd step getting given below messages on the shell:

> 2018-10-09 07:25:51,099 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
>   2018-10-09 07:25:51,099 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1539066382468_0147]

Comment: For the above scenario I'm using 3 ec2 HDP instances and each of them having 4core cpu and 16GB of total Main Memory and below are the configurations for mapred-site and yarn-site.xml.

yarn-site.xml:

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=9216

yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=9216
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=1024

yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio=2.1

mapred-site.xml:

mapreduce.map.memory.mb=3072
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=6144
mapreduce.map.java.opts= -Xmx2457m

mapreduce.reduce.java.opts= -Xmx4915m

Comment: Hi, try to load data without schema or use the direct path without IP address i.e '/user/abc/datadir1' .

Comment: @JAyPaTel I have resolved the issue by increasing the mapreduce map and reduce memory size.